# Connect Delphi XE OSX Firemonkey application with SQLite database

Tags: macos, sqlite, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I need to convert applications wrote in Delphi XE3 to use it on a Mac OSX.
I use for this applicatiopn database SQLite but i cannot found firemonkey compatible components that i can use to connect with my databases.

How can i do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the high-level Delphi database components, then I cannot help you, but if it is about low level database access, without using the Delphi database components, here is what I did:

There is a SQLite interface included with Firemonkey. Include "System.Sqlite", in your uses section. I have only focused on iOS, which does not allow dynamic libraries, so the Firemonkey implementation comes in handy, as it automatically links the SQLite libraries into the executable.

I re-used and modified the SQLite3Wrap.pas, from my previous SQLite wrapper, to use the Firemonkey library and to make it work with NEXTGEN. So far it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to connect from Delphi XE3 to SQLite on Mac OSX, then you can use LiteDAC for this because these components are fully compatible with Firemonkey and support Mac OSX.